# evaluate $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{\overline{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{\overline{z}}$$

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{Im(z)}{\overline{z}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{yi}{x-yi}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{yi}{x-yi}\cdot\frac{x+yi}{x+yi}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{yxi-y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}-\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{yx}{x^2+y^2}$$

taking $y=mx$

$$\lim_{(x,mx)\to (0,0)}-\frac{m^{2}x^2}{x^2(m^2+1)}+i\frac{mx^2}{x^2(m^2+1)}=\lim_{(x,mx)\to (0,0)}-\frac{m^{2}}{m^2+1}+i\frac{m}{m^2+1}$$

And therefore there is no limit, can we use $re^{i\theta}$ to show it?

Comment: What do you mean to solve it? You just showed the limit doesn't exist, what else you want to do?

Comment: How do you intend to use $\;re^{it}\;$ to solve the above?

Comment: Yes, edited the qeustion

Comment: The limit has to be the same along all paths. Along the $x-$axis, 

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x,0)} \dfrac{yi}{x-yi}= \dfrac{0}{x}=0$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y)} \dfrac{yi}{x-yi}= \dfrac{yi}{-yi}=-1$$

So the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Justin $-1$at the end

Comment: Thanks! I got caught up in the ratio not being zero, and forgot about the sign XD

Comment: You have extra $i$ in the numerator: if $z=x+iy$ for real $x$ and $y$, then $\Im z=y\ne iy$.

Comment: @Ruslan, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can also show the nonexistence of the limit by using polar coordinates $z=r e^{it}$. Note that
$$\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\overline z}=\frac{r\cos t}{r e^{-it}}=\frac{\cos t}{e^{-it}} $$
does not depend on $r$, but varies greatly with $t$. For example, the result is $1$ for $t=0$ and $0$ for $t=\frac\pi 2$. But while possible, this is certainly not a simplification against simply considering $h\to 0^+$ with $z=h$ and $z=ih$.

Comment: $Im(z)=r cos(t)$? Should it be an expression of i?

Comment: No, $\Im(z)\in\mathbb{R}$ because $z=\Re(z)+i\Im(z)$.